# Integrated GUI for Python3?

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x

I have been using Python for a bit now (5-6 months) and I would like to finally like to start programming in GUI. Is there a good tutorial for this? Also, I would really like to use something in the default Python language rather than something installed otherwise, unless Py2EXE has been updated to 3.x and it supports other modules (modules? add-ons? I'm trying to say 3rd party GUIs). Thanks!

EDIT: Toolkit? Is that the right word? Also I have used Tkinter and it feels very limited. I could only get buttons to go on the top and it was just weird. Maybe I was doing it wrong. If you have a good tutorial for that, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Look at pynsist for Windows packaging. It has examples for PyGObject, and Qt.

Comment: There are no limitations in tkinter with respect to where buttons or any other widgets go, FWIW.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter is part of python, and it is quite powerful. You have Notebook, Listbox and such...
There are some limitations, and PyQt and PyGTK are more powerful.

My advice will be to start with Tkinter (typing what widget you want + tkinter in your search engine usually works) and see what you can do.

I am not sure I understand your comment about buttons, but if you are talking about layout, the grid method of tkinter is very powerful.